# How to get all months between two dates in SQL-oracle with different range for different clients

Tags: sql, oracle

We are trying to complete a table because we need to calculate different lag values for the numeric variable. Just a sample of our table can be:

```
CLIENT MONTH    VARIABLE
1      201705   45
1      201706   33
2      201603   11
2      201605   22
2      201606   12
```

I need to complete the table adding rows with the missing months and null values for the numeric variable. In our example, the ideal solution was:

```
CLIENT MONTH    VARIABLE
1      201705   45
1      201706   33
2      201603   11
2      201604   NULL
2      201605   22
2      201606   12
```

HINTS (or not...):

In order to solve this question, We are able to:

1) Obtain all months between 2 given dates:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('201304', 'YYYYMM'), LEVEL - 1), 'YYYYMM') MONTHS
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('201708', 'YYYYMM'), TO_DATE('201304', 'YYYYMM'));
```

2) Obtain the min and max dates for each Client:

```
SELECT CLIENT, MIN(MONTH) AS MIN_MONTH, MAX(MONTH) AS MAX_MONTH FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY CLIENT;
```

PD: We are trying to develope this question with a very huge data set (+300.000.000 rows).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always you need two steps:

1. find an algorithm
2. write the query

### Step 1

The problem is that there are month gaps for clients, so we'll have to create these months. Precisely: for each client we want to create all months from min(month) to max(month). Once we have all months per client, we can outer join our table.

**You can stop reading here and try writing the query for yourself, before checking my query.**

### Step 2

```
with pairs (client, month) as
(
  select client, min(month) as month from mytable group by client
  union all
  select client, case when mod(month, 12) > 0 then month + 1 else month + 89 end as month
  from pairs
  where month < (select max(m.month) from mytable m where m.client = pairs.client)
)
select client, month, m.variable
from pairs 
left join mytable m using (client, month)
order by client, month;
```

I'm using standard SQL's recursive CTE here instead of Oracle's `CONNECT BY`. It does the same thing. You may want to translate my query to a `CONNECT BY` query for practice. But usually I'd recommend writing standard SQL queries rather than Oracle-only queries.

Comment: Hi Thorsten. Thank you for your answer but doesn't work. Maybe I was not clear but it's not what we need! Why are you  adding +97? why are you calculating the residual (MOD) ? we just need to incorpore to our data the extra rows with the missing months between min and max months for each client. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Throsten, I already understand you! It was my fault so I wasn't clear. Our table was just an example. We have more than 300.000.00 rows with different Clients and months. We are looking for a generic solutions which allow us to complete the table indistinctly of the month's values. For example, we can have for one client: 201008, 201009, 201012 and we need the 201010 and 201011 with null value.

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of quarters instead of months, hence the 4 (quarters) and 97 (jump to next year). With months we must detect month 12 and add 89 then instead: 201610 + 1 => 201611 + 1 => 201612 + 89 => 201701 + 1 => 201702 ... Sorry, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, yes, we already solved it modifiying your previous code. Thank you very much for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Sometime I get very similar requirements where client wants to see date or time slots to appear even though there is no data present.If SQL code runs frequently within a function querying through millions of record, I usually go for a simple cross join to dummy table and left join data tables for performance.

```
SELECT 
TBL1.CLIENT_ID,
TBL1.MONTHS,
YOUR_FIRST_TBL.VARIABLE 

      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID,
            TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('201304', 'YYYYMM'), LEVEL - 1), 'YYYYMM') MONTHS 
            FROM DUAL

            CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID FROM TABLE1) -- DISTINCT LIST OF CLIENT

            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('201708', 'YYYYMM'), TO_DATE('201304', 'YYYYMM'))) TBL1

LEFT JOIN (SELECT CLIENT, MIN(MONTH) AS MIN_MONTH, MAX(MONTH) AS MAX_MONTH FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY CLIENT) TBL2
ON TBL1.CLIENT_ID  = TBL2.CLIENT 

LEFT JOIN YOUR_FIRST_TBL -- THE FIRST TABLE WITH THE GAPS
ON TBL1.CLIENT_ID = YOUR_FIRST_TBL.CLIENT 
AND TBL1.MONTHS = YOUR_FIRST_TBL.MONTH

WHERE TBL1.MONTHS BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TBL2.MIN_MONTH,'YYYYMM') AND TO_CHAR(TBL2.MAX_MONTH,'YYYYMM')

ORDER BY TBL1.CLIENT_ID, TBL1.MONTHS ;
```